# Unioning two with clauses

Tags: sql-server

Here is the concept of what I am trying to do.

I basically have two sets of data, one for the current info and one for archived info.  I need to union them to show them all in one list.

My query is much more complicated than this but for simplicities sake I've just posted the general idea of what I need to do.

How would I get this to work for me?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
(
    with m1 as 
    (
        select --distinct 
        pfa.FacilityID
        from PatientFormCompleted
    )
    select * from m1
    left join other tables
)
union all
(
    with m1archive as 
    (
        select --distinct 
        pfa.FacilityID
        from PatientFormArchive
    )
    select * from m1archive
    left join other tables
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely this will be closed (voted, not downvoted, myself BTW) but after your edit, you did put some effort in the question, so here goes

You can use multiple `CTE`'s but with the constraint that

- they follow one another
- only the first `WITH` gets written

Please note that you should not use `SELECT *` but be specific in what columns you'd like to return.

**SQL Statement**

```
with m1 as 
(
    select --distinct 
    pfa.FacilityID
    from PatientFormCompleted
)
, m1archive as 
(
    select --distinct 
    pfa.FacilityID
    from PatientFormArchive
)
select * from m1
left join other tables
union all
select * from m1archive
left join other tables
```

Comment: I have a follow up question now.  If I wanted to get a count of all the records returned as one total, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Never mind.  Got it.  Just needed an alias.  Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options:

Union into a single CTE:

```
with m1 as 
(
    select --distinct 
    pfa.FacilityID
    from PatientFormCompleted

    union all

    select --distinct 
    pfa.FacilityID
    from PatientFormArchive

)
select * from m1
left join other tables
```

use more than one CTE:

```
with m1 as 
(
    select --distinct 
    pfa.FacilityID
    from PatientFormCompleted
)
,m1archive as 
(
    select --distinct 
    pfa.FacilityID
    from PatientFormArchive
)
select * from m1
left join other tables
union all
select * from m1archive
left join other tables
```

Comment: +1 on applying the union in the CTE.